# Java - How do I detect if bash has returned?

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, process

I am writing a program in which I want to start a shell in the background, and send and receive the input and output. I already have managed to do this, and can successfully read and write to this process. This is where I run into trouble.

I would like to have a method in `ShellManager` (see below code) that waits until whatever the process is doing finishes/fails, and returns input to the user.

For example, if I send `tar xzf something_that_will_take_a_while.tar.gz`,
I can see in the output how it takes its time, and then echoes this:

```
]0;~
[32mMe@MyComputer [33m~[0m
```

I already tried blocking the thread until `]0;~` was received, this did not work. (Never returned)

I also tried `\u001B`, same problem :(

I'm not sure what the symbol is, and can't find much on how to detect when the process returns.

Here is my code:

```
package buildSystem.shell;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import base.TermConstants;

public class ShellManager {
    private InputStream termOut;
    private OutputStream termIn;

    private ProcessBuilder build;
    private Process main;

    BufferedReader reader;
    BufferedWriter writer;

    public ShellManager() {
        build = new ProcessBuilder(TermConstants.getShellLocation());
        build.redirectErrorStream(true);    
    }

    public void start() throws IOException {
        try {
            main = build.start();
            termOut = main.getInputStream();
            termIn = main.getOutputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(termOut));
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(termIn));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeLine(String s) throws IOException {
        writer.write(s);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
    }

    public String readNextLine() throws IOException {
        return reader.readLine();
    }

    public void end() {
        try {
            writeLine("exit\n");
            main.waitFor();
            termOut.close();
            termIn.close();
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            kill();
        }
    }

    public void kill() {
        main.destroyForcibly();
        try {
            termOut.close();
            termIn.close();
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

/*THE PART I AM HAVING TROUBLE WITH:*/

    public void waitForReturn() {
        try {
            while(reader.readLine() != "\u001B") {}
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I want a reliable way to detect when a program exits from a bash shell. **The bash process will still be running, but the program running from that bash instance will have returned. Because of this I cannot use `process.waitFor()`**.

I tried waiting for `]0;~`, and then the `[32mMe@MyComputer [33m~[0m`, which worked until an tar exited with an error code, in which case the two lines would be reversed. I am unsure how to proceed, as detecting that bash has returned to the user should be a relatively easy task.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You must close the streams before calling `waitFor()`. Ottherwise you have a deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this represents the way you have been trying to match output, it's your problem:

```
while(reader.readLine() != "\u001B") {}
```

Except in special cases, you have to use the `equals()` method on `String` instances:

```
while (true) {
  String line = reader.readLine();
  if ((line == null) || "\u001B".equals(line))
    break;
}
```

I'm not sure why you expect `ESC` and a newline when a process exits though.

Comment: That worked. Honestly, I have no idea why I didn't see that as I usually dont make that mistake. Thanks a lot! Also, I was checking for `esc` just because I had tried everything else I could think of. I completely missed the actual probem, so thanks again for finding it. I still can't believe it was something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call the Process.waitFor() method.
So you need something like:

```
Process p = build.start();
p.waitFor()
```

If you are trying to simulate a bash shell, allowing input of a command, executing, and processing output without terminating. There is an open source project that may be a good reference for code on how to do this. It is available on Git. Take a look at the [Jediterm](https://github.com/JetBrains/jediterm) Pure Java Emulator.

Thinking about simulating a bash, I also found this example for [Piping between processes](https://blog.art-of-coding.eu/piping-between-processes/) also be be relevant.

It does show how to extract the output of a process executing and piping that data as the input into another Java Process. Should be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response! Unfortunately this doesn't work, as while bash is running the process is running, even if it has returned to the user. This would however work if the shell exited after running the command, but that is not what I need. Thanks anyway for your response!

Comment: @TooManyPolygons Your question is how can you tell when bash has returned. If that's not what you really mean, fix your question.

Comment: @erickson I'm not sure what you mean.It specifically states in **bold** letters that I cannot use `process.waitFor()`. (Not at the time the answer was posted, but well before you posted your comment). Why does my question need to be "fixed"? It is very specific. I don't see why showing up 2 months after I replied to an answer and telling me it needs to be revised  is at all helpful. So, no. My question is not "how can you tell when bash has returned", it is much more specific. If you don't like it, please at least try and include a reason why. Did you actually read it?

Comment: And you updated the question after my answer was posted regarding the waitfor(); ;)

Comment: @pczeus Yes, i did :) I appreciate your answer though, even if it was not quite what I needed.

Comment: @TooManyPolygons Your question is literally, "How do I detect if bash has returned?" But, when given the correct answer to *that* question, you rejected it. Sure, I read the rest, and that's why I knew you need to fix your post to clarify what you're looking for. So, ask what you really mean. Apparently you want to detect when some other process, running within `bash` returns, rather than `bash` itself. So say that. Is `tar` producing the output you're looking for? Are you looking for a shell prompt? What? Honestly, I don't understand why something so obvious needs this sort of clarification.

Comment: @erickson After rejecting the answer, I thanked the person for their answer and revised my question extensively. Maybe it was not very clear to you what I was looking for, as I am not extremely familiar with bash/UNIX in general. However, it was answered so I have no need to revise it further, though I will take your advice and try and clarify what I am asking for more in the future.